# why collectstatic does not upload modified files to S3? django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am currently using django and uploading all my statics into S3.
The problem I am having now is, uploading works perfect BUT if I have modified a file let's say `uploading.js` I changed something in there and do `collectstatic` it wouldn't upload the `uploading.js` again.  It will just say `0 files uploaded` I have to go into S3 and delete `uploading.js` THEN run `collectstatic` and it will work.  This is quite bothering though.  I checked a few sites, and they mentioned about uploading time locally and on S3.
I have checked, the files uploaded into S3 is exactly the same timestampe locally that time doesn't seem to be the issue.

Can anyone give me a hand with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my settings

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '##'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '##'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '##'

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static_dev'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media_dev'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

This is my custom_storages.py

```
# class for static storage locations
class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION


# class for media storage locations
class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

Comment: Please show your settings.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Done ^_^